# Adding invalid/valid styling to bootstrap input-group-prepend

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm using Boostrap's form validation for custom styles for my forms. The styling works fine for inputs that have .form-control, but when I use .input-group-prepend, the styling does not get applied to my icons.

Here is my form before validation.

[image: Form before validation]

After Validation

[image: Form After validation]

How can I achieve something like this? (I created this with inspect element)

[image: Preffered Validation]

I added some code to my JS for adding custom styling so that when the user submits the form and its invalid, some custom styling is added to the .input-group-prepend. But when a user inputs the email and password, only the input part goes green, not the "prepend" part.

```
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                    if($(this).attr('id') == 'navbar-login-form'){
                        $('#login-form-button span').empty();
                        $('#login-form-button span').text('Sign in');
                        $('#navbar-login-form .form-group .input-group-prepend').css({
                            "border-top":"1px solid red",
                            "border-left":"1px solid red",
                            "border-bottom":"1px solid red",
                            "border-radius":"10px 0 0 10px"
                        });
                        $("#navbar-login-form .form-group input").attr('style', 'border-left: 0!important');
                    }
```

This kindof works, but I don't really know how to change the red borders to green as soon as the user types the email and password.

[image: Kindof working validation]

How can I achieve this validation styling easily?

Comment: Please consider creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for us.

Answer (score 0):

actually y can just do `echo '<style>.your_input{border-color:green;}</style>';` for example. just put it in the right part of your code